# Como realizo operaciones con punto decimal de un Textbox en C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, interfaz-gráfica

Verán tengo un inconveniente, estoy aprendiendo sobre esto de las interfaces graficas en C# con el Framework .NET, estoy realizando un programa muy sencillo de conversión de °C a °F y viceversa, pero tengo un problema, al momento de convertir valores enteros todo bien, pero si yo quiero ingresar un valor decimal con el punto (.), me salta un error que es el siguente >**System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'**, he hecho validaciones para que en el Textbox con el evento KeyPress, solo se me permitan números y el punto, esto me va bien, pero mi problema es ese, no poder realizar la operación con el punto decimal.

Adjunto código por partes:

```
/*Función que me permite validar los números y el punto (.)*/
public bool solonumeros(int code)
        {
            bool resultado; 

            if (code == 46 && celcius.Text.Contains("."))//se evalua si es punto y si es punto se revisa si ya existe en el textbox
            {
                resultado = true;
            }
            else if ((((code >= 48) && (code <= 57)) || (code == 8) || code == 46)) //se evaluan las teclas validas
            {
                resultado = false;
            }
            else if (!permitir)
            {
                resultado = permitir; //Variable permitir es una variable global del tipo bool
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = true;
            }

            return resultado;

        }
/*Evento KeyPress del TexBox llamado celsius*/
private void celcius_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = solonumeros(Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar)); //llamada a la funcion que evalua que tecla es aceptada
            button1.Enabled=true;
        }
/*Hago lo mismo para la otra conversión*/
/*Parte del código en el cual me da el error en el evento click del botón que dará el resultado*/
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double total = 0.0f;
            total = double.Parse(celcius.Text)*(1.8)+32; //Es aqui en esta linea en la cual me da el error, no se que debo de hacer antes para poder hacer correcta la operacion.
            string resultado = total.ToString();
            reF.Text = resultado;
        }
```

El problema esta explícitamente en esta linea del código que cita así: **total = double.Parse(celcius.Text)*(1.8)+32;**, como le comentaba al realizar las conversiones enteras, todo me da bien, pero al intentar a ser la conversión de un valor decimal, me salta eso.

Cualquier ayuda o consejo es bienvenido, estaré al pendiente.

Comment: si te fijas en tu codigo estas utilizando int con double, cambia todos a double y ya deberia funcionarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la sobre carga del método Parse(), pasando como parámetro en `NumberStyle` (Con el fin de que te permita el punto decimal). Quedaría algo así:

```
double.Parse(inputString,NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)*(1.8)+32
```

Comment: Muchas gracias he investigado un poco y he tenido que utilizar el espacio de nombre system.globalization para realizar la tarea, me he documentado un poco y pude resolver el inconveniente.